# How do I write a bitstring of any length to a binary file in python

Tags: python, binary, byte, binaryfiles

I need to write a bitstring, which isn't always a multiple of 8 to a binary file. I also need to successfully read the string from the file again.

There will never be a 0 at the start of the string.
Example string:

```
bitstring = '10110101111111001101101010011011111010011010110001010101011100010110100010001001110001110100011111010001100011011110010100110000010111101011001011010111111100000110000000001001101000010110000111'
```

I need to use as little storage as possible. So if the string has length 194 (above) I need the file size to be 194//8 + 1 = 25 bytes, although I'm not sure if its possible to store a non-integer amount of bytes in a bin file.

This is the first time I have used binary so excuse the bad practice.

This is my current solution to write to the file:

```
with open(filename,"wb+") as f:
    f.write(bytes(list(map(int, bitstring))))
    f.close()
```

And this to read from it:

```
string = "".join(list(map(str,np.fromfile(filename,"u1"))))
```

using EmEditor, every digit in the string is stored as a 2 digit binary string, which is undesirable. I realise that this is probably because I'm splitting the bitstring into individual digits. Here is the above bitstring shown in the binary editor:

```
01 00 01 01 00 01 00 01  01 01 01 01 01 01 00 00  01 01 00 01 01 00 01 00  01 00 00 01 01 00 01 01 
01 01 01 00 01 00 00 01  01 00 01 00 01 01 00 00  00 01 00 01 00 01 00 01  00 01 01 01 00 00 00 01 
00 01 01 00 01 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 01 00 00 01  01 01 00 00 00 01 01 01  00 01 00 00 00 01 01 01 
01 01 00 01 00 00 00 01  01 00 00 00 01 01 00 01  01 01 01 00 00 01 00 01  00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 
00 01 00 01 01 01 01 00  01 00 01 01 00 00 01 00  01 01 00 01 00 01 01 01  01 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 
00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 01  01 00 01 00 00 00 00 01  00 01 01 00 00 00 00 01 
01 01
```

(All numbers are 2 digits, and file size is 194 bytes, which is the amount of binary numbers in the file/string)

I have tried to use bytearray with the same results

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: [`bitarray`](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) may help. it can encode sequences of bits to bytes (which is suitable for serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Its can be solved by converting the string to integer and write binary integers to file like this

```
import os
from array import *

def main():
    filename = "test.bin"
    bitstring = '10110101111111001101101010011011111010011010110001010101011100010110100010001001110001110100011111010001100011011110010100110000010111101011001011010111111100000110000000001001101000010110000111'
    print(bitstring)

    # split string to 8 bites long chunks
    splits = [bitstring[x:x + 8] for x in range(0, len(bitstring), 8)]
    print(splits)

    bin_array_in = array('B')
    bin_array_out = array('B')

    # convert bits to int and add to list
    for split in splits:
        bin_array_in.append(int(split, 2))

    print(bin_array_in)

    # dump list to file
    with open(filename, "wb+") as f:
        bin_array_in.tofile(f)
        f.close()

    print("file size: {}".format(os.path.getsize(filename)))

    # get the list from file
    with open(filename, "rb+") as f:
        bin_array_out.fromfile(f, len(bin_array_in))
        f.close()

    print(bin_array_out)

    # convert back to bin and join to one string 
    bitstring = ""
    for i in bin_array_out:
        bitstring += "{:08b}".format(i, "08b")

    print(bitstring)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There is only one problem, the last byte is padded with 0 to make 8 bits chunk.
A dont know if its more easy to change read / write logic or make your initial string `% 8` so i let you figure out this part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> bitstring = '10110101111111001101101010011011111010011010110001010101011100010110100010001001110001110100011111010001100011011110010100110000010111101011001011010111111100000110000000001001101000010110000111'
>>> a = int(bitstring, 2)
>>> a
17849302729865679414224788101014796653923247039249910236551L
>>> bin(a)[2:] == bitstring
True
```

Once you have converted your bitstring into an integer, you may write it to the file the usual way. And read it back. And convert back to the bitstring (see above) and get the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to hiro protagonist who suggested using bitarray, as it was the simplest implementation I could do (Couldn't mark comment as an answer).Thanks for the answers but using bitarray I could solve it using fewest lines of code.

Here's the solution:
write:

```
bitstring = "11010101001101010011101"
bitarr = bitarray([0 for _ in range(8-(len(bitstring)%8))] + list(map(int,bitstring)))

with open(filename,"wb+") as f:
    bitarr.tofile(f)
```

read:

```
with open(filename, "rb") as f:
string = "".join(_reformat_bin(list(map(str,np.fromfile(string,"u1")))))

while not int(string[0]):
    string = string[1:]
```

_reformat_bin() converts an array of strings representing numbers 0-255 to an arr of strings representing bytes e.g.

```
>>> _reformat_bin(["255", "0", "9"])
>>> ["11111111", "00000000", "00001001"]
```

Cheers all.